# Three other numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

Given three distinct numbers from \$1\$ to \$7\$, output three other distinct numbers from \$1\$ to \$7\$, that is having no numbers in common with the original numbers. Your code must produce a different output set for each possible input set. That is, no two inputs can produce the same output, treating both as unordered sets. Other than that, you can implement whatever mapping you want.

More mathematically, you're asked to give a bijection (one-to-one function) \$f:S \to S\$ where \$S\$ consists of three-element subsets of \$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\$, such that \$f(s) \cap s = \emptyset\$ for every \$s\in S\$. As a bijection, this mapping has to be invertible, though you don't have to provide the inverse function in your code.

[Here are the 35 possible triples](https://tio.run/##RcvBCoMwDADQ8/IVObZMBupBEPoxOrotaJOSxINf323ssHd/9fSX8NAalSrqSJ7VRXYD4DTBlkbgoxgm1IWfOfQd8rWPAA9RtGO1/Dn8b7e7lJV4cRK28K0dbnGGS1Vix53Mw6/F1t4) (written [space-separated](https://tio.run/##RczBCsIwDADQs/mKsFOLYzA9CMK@RDxsUjVuTUqTwfz6avHgB7yX3vYUPpRCMUk2JAvZRBYF4OEE83AEXqPigHnkR3B9i7zvPcBdMuo6afga/rPuJnEiHo2E1VXa4uzPsEuZ2LDBpnsJsbuoZbd5rM1Wh4XU3C/0V1/KBw)).

**I/O**

The format of the three-element sets is flexible. You can take the inputs in sorted order as three numbers or a three-element list/array/tuple, or as a set. You may not, however, require ordered inputs in a specific order other than sorted. You may zero index.

You may also use a sequence of seven bits of which three are on. This seven-bit sequence can also be represented as as a decimal number, byte, or character.

Output can be given in any of these formats, with the further allowance that ordered outputs don't have to be sorted.

Comment: Either this is trickier than it looks or I'm drunker than I think!

Comment: May we take input (or output) from \$0\$ to \$6\$ instead?

Comment: Is it reasonable to return the single number not included in either of the two sets?

Comment: @att No, you need to return the set.

Comment: If it didn't have to be bijective, we could have `127-x&127+~x` using the bit-set I/O format

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:([*{*range(7)}-s]*4)[-sum(s):][:3]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY67bsMwDEV3fQWRiTSaLm5QQIC/xPGg1FIiQA9DpIfC8Lc7Sp0ADcfLc8g7/cotp3Zz3XkLJl5GA6yxb5ammHS1@E3rkYfmi/ojzxGZ9NDrdthcyRG82CI5BwYfp1wEfnK8@GTE58RKFctzEIYO2AqScrlARdMbhq8/H9CSVlBn96rm8CEy0V88FZ8E3WHhVcOyQ@uB/in8acYRZZ6CRa597Ij7guoJZZhrXQw2PVMm6DpoT7TdAQ)**

Comment: Ooh, repeating the list to avoid modulus on rotations is smart. Can't believe I didn't remember that; must have been too long since I've done this sort of stuff

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
def f(b):c=[*{*range(7)}-b];del c[-sum(b)%4];return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NCoMwEIXX5hSDUIiibiwUKvYi4iKJsQ3oJGTGRSk9u03B0t3H4/2FJz88tvs@2RlmqYur6YfyVUaFdysvxbvWYzfZBcxQ07Ymw@k8dtHyFhHM7tbgI4NjG9n7hYSIlraFCXoYRiFmH4HA4d/RGL9qh4qdR5K/mQra4ioylWJkWVIhMp14lipRiA5Zqgry/pZXoJOkiFIfaEDP3/pjVWQHNCoEi1O6u38A)

-3 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman
-4 bytes by zero-indexing
-1 byte thanks to xnor

Comment: Nice solution! How does the bijectiveness work? I'm trying to think of an argument that explains why a collision isn't possible, but it's tricky. Because it's the number in a given sorted position that's removed, it seems like in theory this could create a collision where two different numbers in two different positions are removed producing the same set.

Comment: @xnor Honestly, I just brute forced all numbers `x,y,z` in the range `[0,10)` and found the ones where `b[0]*x + b[1]*y + b[2]*z` would not result in any collisions, and found `x=y=z=3` and `x=y=z=7` as the two options that would be golfiest. In other words, I have absolutely no proof and just did trial and error until I found one :P

Comment: Well, there's something weird and impressive going on here. This same thing doesn't seem to hold for parameters other than 7 and 3. It seems to hinge on the following result: Inside any four-element \$T\$ of \$S\$, there is *exactly one* element \$x \in T\$ such that the number of elements of \$S-T\$ that are less than \$x\$ is equal modulo 4 to \$x - \mathrm{sum}(T)\$.

Comment: Code demonstrating the above: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NSsUwEEbXmaeYzYUE4l2oIIh5EnGRext1uPkjSaX15WumLVTEXZI533wneW6fKd4vC4WcSkNqrrSUfAWI5glu5gHiGCoaLDZ@OBkVwHsqWMdLdR2PR@J8TeFC0TZKsUpOabypZxA7a9BTbXK7KRAdz94FF3lUe7kbZJ@sSYV3yOcd7qWC4kBXxyavdQzSvkzIIpYddmx9mPjh2P0GIqRh9MRBOfHenj7mSuEJH/9PgkhfrnibWbCnJmPmjdQzs9@U5a6lcWtZVXOh/qlNSv/aqPEPrXEvWJYf "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: By the way, you can change `sum(b)*3%4` to `-sum(b)%4` to save a byte.

Comment: @xnor oh, that's cool. It also worked for -9, (and -1; thanks for the byte save), so i presume also -5 (and then any x===3 mod 4) (**edit** wait that's just how modular arithmetic works)

Comment: I think I figured out why it's a bijection and have a proof. It turns out that the inverse map is the same code except you replace `-sum(b)` with `(1-sum(b))`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NCsIwEIXXzSkGQUikLYiC0FIvUrpI2kQD7SRkpgsRz14jKO4@Hu8vPvge8LRtk3XgpFHN2PWH5yFpvFl5Ua/KDO1kZxh7eaxoXbJF7c9DmyyvCWHc/BJDYvBsE4cwkxDJ0jozQQf9IIQLCQg8/h31GBbjUbMPSPK3VMJJNaLQOUaWJSlRmMxO6kwxeWSpS9h1110JJkuaKPeBAQz8qf@uiuILtY7R4pT/bm8 "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Here, the `1` is the sum of `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` modulo 4.

Comment: @xnor That's cool! I wonder if there's a generalized approach to this; I mean technically my solution _is_ a proof since it has a finite number of cases and validating all of them _proves_ it but that's a technicality.

Comment: Amazing... I discovered the same when constructing my Jelly solution AND I started with sum * 3 and golfed to -sum.

Comment: One speculative explanation for the parameters 7 and 3 is that the smallest [finite projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes) has seven points/lines, and every line contains three points/every point lies on three lines. For the next smallest projective plane, 7 and 3 are replaced by 13 and 4, respectively; I wonder whether there's anything to trying this same algorithm with those parameters.

Comment: Actually, this works with whatever parameters in place of 7 and 3; I was mistaken about this before. I just needed to replace the `4` in `%4` with their difference.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9 8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
7RṚḟṙSḊ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of the three numbers, from \$[1,7]\$, in sorted order which yields a list of other numbers, from \$[1,7]\$, not necessarily sorted.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//N1LhuZrhuJ/huZlT4biK////WzEsIDIsIDNd)** Or see [all 35](https://tio.run/##RY0xCsJAEEWvsoXlNs7MJuAxtJKQ0ibkApbaCN5AG8HaA2Qh2IgHmVxktVh4xcBjePw3HMbxWEq79Xz36eH5tvPpWr7z5@L5uVrOr@F/y@m9CftSum4dg8SgfQwVDUxgA7YVFVdxFVdxDcEQDCHxTXybikJNqAk1oSbUhJpQE2pCTagpC8qCsqAsKAvKgiEYgiGkiv0P) (I sorted the resulting values for easier comparison).

#### How?

```
7RṚḟṙSḊ - Link: list A                   e.g.  [2,4,7]
7R      - seven range                          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  Ṛ     - reverse                              [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
   ḟ    - filter discard (A) -> B              [6,5,3,1]
     S  - sum (A)                              13
    ṙ   - rotate (B) left by (that)            [5,3,1,6]
      Ḋ - remove the leftmost                  [3,1,6]
```

Comment: Do you actually need ```N$```?  Isn't it just-as-effective to rotate left as to rotate right?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen there is no rotate right atom, but I can reverse the list prior to filtering and dequeue at the end rather than pop which saves a byte.

Comment: What I meant was, if you leave-out ```N$``` you're effectively rotating left (since you're rotating by a positive number now), and it seems to be Ok, I think: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY0xCsJAEEWvsoXlNs6fTcBjaCUhpU3IBSy18QaClWDtAQxIGvEgm4usFguvGHgMj/@GwzgeS2m3@XXP022Xp2v5vj@XPD1Wy/k5/G85zZuwL6Xr1jFYDOpjqOhgAhuwrShc4QpXuI7gCI6Q@Ca@TUWjZtSMmlEzakbNqBk1o2bUxIJYEAtiQSyIBUdwBEdIFfsf)...  or am I missing something obvious...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen that produces repeats (e.g 123 and 135 give the same output)

Comment: Yes.  Sorry.  I thought I'd looked, but apparently not very carefully.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I think what you're missing is the modular nature, i.e. rotating A left by x is like rotating A right by len(A)-x.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes by using modulo `-4` (which returns the negative of modulo `4`)*

```r
(1:7)[v<--scan()][sum(v)%%-4-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDRSsMwFIbv8xTHSkeCyUXXyaBYQfDaF6hFspraQJfUnGTDp69Ny2ZVyNWfP9/5Ttw40qzYs@r0IAQ20lBWVxiO9MTSVOxEVo8Z2ZKckFtwSpyd9gokQhtM47U14C14hR5k30MjUWFB2vJyO1EWujjVlaCRKyJ4d5exOiLnp6g8wgZs8EPwBYnZW8zKxh4Phu55zpbQKQz9lMth6L/otce3vGVX2rlTvlNuFlqQYMLxoByCdAreNXo92cHTyzMY62GYqMp40GY6q3ZBGulp8moSRiYWxWVqVuT3/LqfZjdUmpVLxXWdapOufWPG2GZDe2U@fEeD0Z9B0f@VsswZmzfBzp4v9q1169/9sZouqI7e0YnFfJDo1W8Z3ti@lwOqMuEJ44l4TPiqtpr/tznPGL8B)

Finds the 4 digits in 1..7 that aren't in the input, and excludes the one corresponding to the input sum (wrapping around).

TIO link tests that outputs are unique for each input, and shows output for every input.

```r
(1:7)                   # vector of digits 1..7
     [          ]       # select elements
         -scan()        # excluding (negative indexes) input
      v<-               # and define v as (negative) input
                        # (so up to here we have the 4 elements that aren't in the input)  
     [              ]   # from these, select elements
      -                 # excluding (negative index)
       (sum(v)%%4+1)    # the sum of input, modulo 4, plus 1
```

Comment: Very nice! The exclusion rule is clever.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

As [previously advertised](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212240/three-other-numbers/212242?noredirect=1#comment499586_212240), I'm a wee bit tipsy so this could well be wrong and, even if right, could probably be golfed a little.

```
7õ kU kÏ¶UxÍu4
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=N/Uga1Uga8%2b2VXjNdTQ&input=WzEsMiwzXQ) or [view (what I think is) the proof](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=N/UK4DMgyysiIC0%2bICIrVWtEIGvPtkR4zXU0)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⁻¹²⁷⁺θＸ²⊟Φ⁷№ＥTXdhp﹪×℅λＸ²ι¹²⁷θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUy7CsJAEOz9ipBqD2JhEERSBoQUpylS2J65QBY29z79/HMDFk4zM8xjXlWYraJSBuNyuufttQTwojuMAU2CXsUEEk2OcGovTTUSK89sP9xrd@HghpTYcdzbzCOpHNTTU6@ubippdSYLE25LhEfQaBQBib8LFOz4fScvfuhKOV/L8U1f) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is as a 7-bit integer `7..112`. Explanation: The ordinals of the string `TXdhp` have five bit patterns which I have arbitrarily chosen to be such that the result excludes `1`. They are then cyclically rotated until one matches the input, at which point I have determined the excluded bit. This bit is then added to the original input, and finally the difference between `127` and the sum is printed.

```
Ｎθ                                  Cast input to integer
             ⁷                      Literal 7
            Φ                       Filter on implicit range
                TXdhp               Literal string `TXdhp`
               Ｅ                    Map over characters
                        λ           Current character
                       ℅            Ordinal
                      ×             Multiplied by
                          ²         Literal 2
                         Ｘ          Raised to power
                           ι        Outer index
                     ﹪              Modulo
                            ¹²⁷     Literal 127
              №                     Count (i.e. contains)
                               θ    Input
           ⊟                        Pop matching value
          ²                         Literal 2
         Ｘ                          Raised to that power
       ⁺                            Added to
        θ                           Input
   ⁻                                Subtracted from
    ¹²⁷                             Literal 127
  Ｉ                                 Cast to string
                                    Implicitly print
```

I arbitrarily chose the following five bit patterns to exclude `1` but any five even cyclically distinct patterns would work.

```
T   1010100
X   1011000
d   1100100
h   1101000
p   1110000
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>66</s>  65 bytes

Takes input as a 3-digit string. Returns a string in the same format.

```javascript
f=(n,k=i=0)=>++k<8?(~n.search(k)||n*43%399%4==i++?'':k)+f(n,k):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY@9TsMwFIX3PsVdKtskRNTXSWmKW6UbE0NHxBClLrgJTtWkRUIVrx5yYEAsRz4/n2wfykvZVSd/7G9Du3PDsLcyxLX19k7ZVRTVD/dr@RWSzpWn6k3W6noNN4anvFhMjbU@itZC5LWK9sBULsRQkKXnmeaYZtpAUkgGmY/CyBgZI2NkBtbAGtgUpxSnbBQNQoPQIDQIDUKD0CA0CA1Cg2C0jJbRMlpGy2gNrIE1sGk2f1lOJpvx1UXyXh5lILui8TsUkRBKjV3Vhq5tXNK0r1I8BspJjGWRHFofpKCf0b/N07n/3Wz@NjEJiSi4D9q6Xm5U0vlPh1to57veh6qnS9mcXaeEWg7f)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/Codepage)

```
7LsKsO(._¨
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xCcMwFAVXUZlCGPzel71AugQygDEhBheuXGipLJAFMkBWUhrBdcfjeHfW13bs7fe5tvleb/VxGZ7fd2vLMuaknLzm1DHAAk7g3NG4xjWucQMhEAKhsBbWqaOoiZqoiZqoiZqoiZqoiZp5MA/mwTyYB/MQCIEQCKXj@gc)**

#### How?

```
7LsKsO(._¨ - (push the input)      e.g.: [2,4,7]
7          - push 7                      7,[2,4,7]
 L         - range                       [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,4,7]
  s        - swap top two of the stack   [2,4,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
   K       - push a without bs           [1,3,5,6]
    s      - swap top two of the stack   [2,4,7],[1,3,5,6]  (implicit input swapped in)
     O     - sum                         13,[1,3,5,6]
      (    - negate                      -13,[1,3,5,6]
       ._  - rotate a left by b          [6,1,3,5]
         ¨ - remove rightmost            [6,1,3]
           - implicit print top of stack [6,1,3]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>84</s> 83 bytes

Saved a whopping <s>16</s> <s>19</s> 23 bytes thanks to the man himself [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!!!

```c
p;i;f(m){for(p=i=0;(L"᰸ᨴᘬᤲᔪ"[p]>>i%7&m)-m;p+=++i%7<1);p=(64>>i%7)+m^127;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPNjpswEIDveQoLaStYJhI2/yJwqXrrG2xSBIRsLAWCEreljehT9NAH6KFa9VBVPfR1eJLsGMhuUFnVwrJn/M2Ph3E2v8@y87kKeLBRC@202R/UKuShEahvlfbX3/bHn/bbz/b77/brg3JXraKI37ivCm1eBJUe6jpKC6oFVag6Vnem6cU7ytygOfNSkCLhparNTjOCQyryusozka/vViQkJ0oZUMPAaYHnge2A74GLewa2Aa4BngU2A9cBywLmge@Ca4JHwfLB8YFRMF2gJlgUmA0O7n0wbaAIMGAOuGB6wDCG1QRdCtk2OdyS46ci3e/6FJRl/YYta/81TlsBci2bymAmM@flOq/RwuhVWCiiSn2COhrgsgiJHRBdT7QOGEEpQgnRJZhK0JFg@gyO4AzhtIczCbsSzjRyGuGXvFIu4mMu0EalZLEgX@aJhsYXIb0WMi34x0d1QC8bVblZk/6bRwTrkABJgUwZyKCHXHxIdhhzow7xXwBFXlSI9fw0Uua1eK7r9fi45btclS6mLv@UC7/fimJ/FPG@zNFRHKfv@U7wMs7E58FaFnPSQRdcD8dOptGrQmF9pKE2DQ537pYo@p/r5uU/clyWGGno1qeX0zUi9u6lqquJNPBhSmp80Mya8yM)

Takes input as \$3\$ bits set in the least-significant-\$7\$-bits of an `int` and returns the three other numbers likewise.

#### Explanation (before some golfs)

```c
f(m){                                  // function taking an integer with  
                                       // 3 bits set in its 7 lsb  
                                       // representing the 3 input numbers  
     for(                              // loop over  
         p=L"ᔪᘬᤲᨴ᰸"                     // a sequence of 5 int values:
                                       //   5418,5676,6450,6708,7224
                                       // that are the 5 unique patterns of    
                                       // 3 set bits per 7 bits shifted and
                                       // repeated over 13 bits so that their  
                                       // 7th bit is unset:  
                                       //   5418 = 1010100101010
                                       //   5676 = 1011000101100  
                                       //   6450 = 1100100110010  
                                       //   6708 = 1101000110100  
                                       //   7224 = 1110000111000
                    ;;++p)             // no need to test for stopping  
                                       // since we must match one  
       for(i=7;i--;)                   // loop over shift values from 6 to 0    
         if((*p>>6-i&m)==m)            // if a shifted 7-bit slice of one of  
                                       // our patterns matches m we've found  
                                       // the correct bit to exclude from m's  
                                       // 4 unset bits
            return(1<<i)+m^127;        // add that bit to m and flip the 7   
                                       // lsb so the 3 other unset bits are  
                                       // now set to represent the 3 return
                                       // values  
 }
```

Comment: Save 1 byte by using `p>>i` and `64>>i`.

Comment: @Neil Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```ruby
->s{n=s.sum;(([*1..7]-s)*9)[-n..-n+2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRC4IwFEbf/RUXfdkEL4REBM0/YhJTJw3mVt7todTfvjTq9TvnfFNoX3EQ11hUNDNW5wfEU1MQz88cjSTPCCmMHAc9kYdyjZOiYDyBgLpJ2K5z9O4msXNjq6302llWclSyu0PvYDFLAvAIW5Jms1mhqCCbh9o0a7qB/93lAvuWKNsnX/kHMFj9RNJvBUJAeYwf)

Stealing [Eric's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212275/98691) which based on [Jonathan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212249/65905). I would've commented to Eric, but i do not have enough reputation.

The actual difference: Using a range to get the three elemented slice.

Comment: Nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
>3-%R7t*5s
```

Takes input as a 3-element list of {0, …, 6}.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/385YVzXIvETLtPj//2gDHQVDHQWjWAA) Or see [all 35 inputs](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/381dLznUXMGYS8fdzlhXNci8RMu02N39/38A).

#### How it works

```
         sQ   sum of input
       *5     multiply by 5
      t       subtract 1
   %R7        take each element of [0, that) mod 7
  -        Q  remove elements present in input
>3            last 3 elements
```

It’s helpful to preserve symmetry under rotations modulo 7, since that leaves just five equivalence classes to consider.  A good starting point is the “average” \$\frac{x + y + z}{3}\$, where division by 3 is the same as multiplication by 5 modulo 7.  It happens that if we start walking down from the average minus 2, taking the first three numbers that aren’t in the input set, the five equivalence classes are conveniently mapped one-to-one:

- {0, 1, 6} ↦ {3, 4, 5} = {0, 1, 6} + 4
- {0, 2, 5} ↦ {1, 3, 4} = {3, 5, 6} + 5
- {0, 3, 4} ↦ {1, 2, 5} = {0, 3, 4} + 5
- {1, 2, 4} ↦ {0, 3, 5} = {0, 2, 5} + 5
- {3, 5, 6} ↦ {1, 2, 4} = {1, 2, 4} + 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
hṙ_Σ¹`-ḣ7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr//9o4bmZX86jwrlgLeG4ozf///9bMiw0LDdd)

Comment: This is really nice.  I just tried before looking at this, and ended-up with ```Ṡfo≠→%4Σ⁰€fo¬€⁰ḣ7```...  17 bytes, which now seems ridiculous looking at your 9 bytes!  Well done.

Comment: Ah!  ```-``` = list difference.  I knew there should be something like that hiding among the commands...  but didn't find it!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen want an explanation?

Comment: I've worked-through it myself by now (and learned a lot), but anyway I do think it's nice to generally include an explanation, especially while Husk is language of the month...

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->s{(([*1..7]-s)*9).last(s.sum).first 3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRC4IwFEbf/RUXfdkEL4REBM0/YhJTJw3mVt7todTfvjTq9TvnfFNoX3EQ11hUNDNW5wfEU1MQz88cjSTPCCmMHAc9kYdyjZOiYDyBgLpJ2K5z9O4msXNjq6302llWclSyu0PvYDFLAvAIW5Jms1mhqCCbh9o0a7qB/93lAvuWKNsnX/kHMFj9RNJvBUJAeYwf)

Ruby port of Jonathan's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212249/65905).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```perl
sub{@c=grep!/[@_]/,0..6;splice@c,-sum(@_)%4,1;@c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDRaoMwFIbv@xSppJqMmNR2K6gN5AG2y11ZKZvYLpuNWRIvhvjqc8bC6Ni5OXDO938Hjq5N8zDCEx9t99qLip9NrZesEMeSkTWlu9zqRla1qEhsuwsSR7y6J0kuqmHMF8LV1vHLiy485Rgric/3S4YopneHhIUhQ8U63pX4b2M5TPZwE4Zws4fbIVonm4jSKE3TaNIa7wTvrVQoikgIT0jAI8YEzAc90Ps7oKnV2b2hacf5dtqagSOcL7SRyoFAKt25DADRF7c6ryKzqBwOKvjF287NvDC301kCqrZTXjVXQOc0Df6nryDolPzMJu6j/rJoZfAVHb9b7WSr7Bg/PUrrsuzZyYZPb/0B)

Just a translation of the python answer from HyperNeutrino.

Comment: Would an answer based on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212249/65905 be shorter?

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```scala
b=>1.to(7).diff(b).zipWithIndex.filter(_._2!=b.sum*3%4)map(_._1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc4xa8MwEAXgPb/iOgTuihHYDhQKDnT04ClDhlCMZJ@IiiMp1iWEhP521@6SIevje3cvdXrQUzA/3Ak02nngm7DvE3zF@FgBXPUA9hNq3/ON@x2fD7WXb6i2r9Fkqm2uJOAHqd5Zi4bU3cW9k@O/VdYNwiO2qi3eKqPS5fRerjd00nHJcpoAMAcJMB@QsGOZiUksCUtSi0rLX0wZWEyzeC4gWhqNjsqGkXV3xDg6L4On1e/0ZJhnRVbSHw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, then! I'm very happy to see someone else using Scala :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
7ɾ$⊍?∑N$ǔṫ$
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=7%C9%BE%24%E2%8A%8D%3F%E2%88%91N%24%C7%94%E1%B9%AB%24&inputs=%5B2%2C4%2C7%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
1∘↓+/⌽(⌽⍳7)∘~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCsJAEEV7T5FSEZHM7CYHsDGVYLxAQGIjaGtjIwQRExQRvIWFtY1HmYvENb5i9zPvf16xXY@Wu2K9WbVtbMeHVbfh2M7vfnhWv9JBYPu2tOpidWPNPZvZ6fB5qlXXcOXzSfgX0yxvyyiOJNLePx3pyYRMu1R6pVd6pXdwB3dwz@25ky4Fn@ATfIJP8Ak@wSf4BJ/gU/bKXtkre2Wv7B3cwR3c//IL)

This is an atop of a train

```apl
1∘↓+/⌽(⌽⍳7)∘~
      (⌽⍳7)∘~ ⍝ Right side of the atop
        ⍳7    ⍝ Range
       ⌽     ⍝ Reverse
           ∘  ⍝ Composed with...
            ~ ⍝ ...without (to remove our arguments)
     ⌽        ⍝ Rotated by...
   +/         ⍝ ...the sum of the arguments
1∘↓           ⍝ Left side of the atop
1∘↓           ⍝ Drop leftmost (drop curried with 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>35</s> 63 bytes

based on the [hyper-neutrino♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212242/80745)'s solution

+28 bytes thanks @DLosc

```powershell
param($a)$b=1..7|?{$_-notin$a}
$b|%{$s+=$_}
$b|?{$_-ne$b[$s%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJRa8IwFIXf8ysuEmeLnWCS6lOZsB@wMdmTSGklYw5tXdIyRtvf3mWm9Zinc8/9cs5Dcil/tLGf@nTq@Qcl1PSXzGTngGchz5PlYrFunxqePhZldSx41jGet9OG23nC0@vgt5rnO26nat/1HWObgEXBMiIRkQxvUkHGkCvI9SAlWAlWgpVgFQAFQAGI4cZwV4MUaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaJNIkEiQSJBIkEiQSFAAFAAFIB4lC6mlKTWM3OGZMdmve16e@tloW58qZzy4V/fb62L3un2ubVWeX/Ivfaj2G3///2zL2hy0uzLx/OS2eRvDJkOuX3X3VZbmCUXDwDoWzOri@F3rWTRzX4uGIdyN@OJQ1kVF7mdRMHqtLY2z3q9s6Il9/wc)

Comment: "Either this is trickier than it looks or I'm drunker than I think!"

Comment: *+80% byte count* ♬ You're welcome! ♬ ;^)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
∑5*‹ʁ7%⊍Ḣ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%915*%E2%80%B9%CA%817%25%E2%8A%8D%E1%B8%A2&inputs=%5B0%2C1%2C2%5D&header=&footer=)

Porting Pyth saves two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
7LIм{3.$IO(._Dg<£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3Mfzwp5qYz0VT38NvXiXdJtDi///jzbSMdExjwUA)

It's a much longer version of the Jelly answer, so go upvote that too.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 20 bytes

Prompts for input of a vector of integers

```
3↑(-+/¯2↑n)⌽n←(⍳7)~⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##LYyxDsFQFIb3PkXHNpQ45159CR6iqVQkTUlMIowljSsMmCwmmwGLxMKbnBepq/2n/5zv//NFkzQYzKJ0PAziNJpOR3Ep20O/J/mOHVmvkpIl33tBo/25kb0yXzbvzLaemHvoL@24tDNHzNmV4jJv2lrMU8xDiqOY1/8w1xouqGnvlv6eLC0Tp@OSy06dCqmRXWRYJaNn9Iye0StwBa7ANX6Nv1slwUfwEXwEH8FH8BF8BB/BR/Ax9ow9Y8/YM/aMvQJX4ApcV/kD)

Comment: @Ven Thanks but I am afraid my ancient APL+WIN interpreter does not support trains.