# Injectively saturate bit strings

Tags: code-golf, binary, open-ended-function, restricted-complexity

It can be easily proven using Hall's marriage theorem that given fixed \$n\$ and \$k<n/2\$, [there is an injective (one-to-one) function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562859/extending-k-element-subsets-of-an-n-element-set-to-k1-element-subsets) from all \$n\$-bit strings with \$k\$ ones to \$n\$-bit strings with \$k+1\$ ones such that an input and its corresponding output differ by exactly one bit. For example, with \$n=5,k=2\$:

```
00011 -> 00111
00110 -> 01110
01100 -> 11100
11000 -> 11001
10001 -> 10011

00101 -> 01101
01010 -> 11010
10100 -> 10101
01001 -> 01011
10010 -> 10110
```

However, the proof is non-constructive. It would be nice to have an explicit construction.

### Task

Given a nonempty \$n\$-bit string with \$k<n/2\$ ones, output an \$n\$-bit string with \$k+1\$ ones formed only by changing one zero in the input to one, such that the \$\binom nk\$ distinct inputs map to \$\binom nk\$ distinct outputs. You must prove that your program has this property.

The bit strings may be represented in any reasonable format, including as decimal numbers and as subsets of a specified \$n\$-element set. You may also simply output the index of the changed bit rather than the full string.

**The output must be deterministic** — it is not allowed to simply change the first zero in the input each time for example; there must be exactly one mapping implemented for each valid \$(n,k)\$ pair. The program or function must also work for all valid \$(n,k)\$ pairs *in theory*, and have at most polynomial time complexity in \$n\$.

Otherwise this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

---

This question was based on [this MathsSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4641994/357390), which at the time of posting this question had no answers. There is now [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642385/357390) by Mike Earnest giving an injection that satisfies this challenge's constraints:

- Repeatedly delete occurrences of `10` in the bitstring. This leaves a string of the form `0...01...1` with at least one zero.
- Change the rightmost remaining zero (at its original location) to a one.

```
100011010001011
XX   XXXX  XX
  001    00  11
    X    X
  00      0  11
          ^ change this to 1
```

Comment: Changing the first zero bit to a one bit isn't even injective anyway e.g. n=3, k=1, it would change both 100 and 010 to 110.

Comment: @Neil That clause is to prevent answers from effectively returning a new mapping _each time_.

Comment: "be actually able to handle random bit strings in the following cases in reasonable time"  Probably better to specify a complexity restraint to make this less subjective.

Comment: @Jonah yes, now?

Comment: Related: [Three other numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/212240/20260), which asks for the \$n=7\$, \$k=3\$ case, but taking the complement of the output set to make it disjoint from rather than a superset of the input.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 51 bytes

```python
lambda n,k,s:sorted(set(range(n))-s)[-sum(s)%(n-k)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY8xbsMwDEV3nYJLARGRiwZZigA6ROe2gxxLjWGLEkR66Dk6dvHS3im3qeS0RSaS-I_8n5_f-V3OidbLUygpwii-SEozwxhzKgKnFPuRnIyJGBzDKfZqI6OT8y2kyMAEFvYPBg5KBfvytUjoHi-H2cV-cEBmMnzkyvtBsxddHL15TYgd43PHS9SMd5q6CV9_Vz-cbSCqkArUSNTs__fMhEcFYoPeTleQERXkMlJtjbTeypJnr_9cd1oMNsgx10dh9rRFyYjWTrt9Fe7dMNRZ3RCuiu3F5oPXaOt6rT8)

This is based on [hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212242/18957) to the 'three other numbers' challenge. Edit: I now believe I have proved its correctness.
Here's a proof by contradiction:

Assume that \$f\$ is not injective. Then there must exist \$s,x,y\$ where \$|s|=k-1\$, \$f(s∪\{x\})=y\$ and \$f(s∪\{y\})=x\$. Take \$x<y\$ without loss
of generality, then
$$\sum s+y\equiv-p_x\bmod n-k$$
$$\sum s+x\equiv-p_y\bmod n-k$$
$$y-x\equiv p_y-p_x\bmod n-k$$
where \$p_x\$ and \$p_y\$ are the indices into the corresponding 'rest' arrays. But \$p_y-p_x\$ is just the number of integers in between \$x\$ and \$y\$ which are not in \$s\$. Let \$m\$ be the number of values in \$s\$ which are between \$x\$ and \$y\$. We have \$m=(y-x)-1-(p_y-p_x)\$, so \$m\equiv-1\bmod n-k\$. Therefore \$n-k-1\le m\le k-1\$, implying \$k\ge n/2\$. But this contradicts the initial assumption that \$k<n/2\$.

Comment: In your code, `rest` looks like it's a set, which Python can't index because its sets are unordered. Do you mean to sort it first and make it a list?

Comment: @xnor Yes, thanks; I lost the list(..) in some refactoring. I'm not sure if you need to sort or not, but I added it just to be sure.

Comment: This answer has been referenced in my answer to the source MSE question!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
s;((1(?2)*0)|0)*\K0;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/YWkPDUMPeSFPLQLPGQFMrxtvA2vD/f0MDAwNDQwMwBWT8yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA)

This implements the injection described [by Mike Earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4641994/injection-from-binary-strings-with-i-bits-to-i1-bits/4642385#4642385): take the longest prefix consisting of balanced pairs of `1`, `0` or unpaired `0`s, and change the rightmost unpaired `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 75 bytes

Modified from [@user1502040's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258091/110802)

```
Module[{d=-Mod[Total[s],n-k]},Sort[Complement[Rangen-1,s]][[If[d==0,1,d]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBasMwDL3nK8Suc6Cht2Ue69bLYIOxdCchire4aUgim8o9hXx7pmajMBsj8aT3nuTBpaMfXGq/3cxgoViVWadxXWbZAXlvoNMne4I7C/NbqM@9x7G2uaa4C8n1KGQ472gyVTglfA5D7P3gOeGH48ZzXhghQnw5YG3tyhSmJj2zU5dxKrNtQNH0k9vAKEJlBpAUUHc1V@8FeT@1qrgLVdKkeRS4f4AbvRquYFo641VsE6PnGsVAoqW0EfE64qvnJh0xElgLHdxCsVQvA/1RnIFIBkZRbnX@Ep/kdxtkghwKLXUTTUr7L@kWyaeWw9Dqz1wWUOf5Bw)